# Как добавить питон в PATH на windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как добавить питон в PATH на windows 10

Comment: Первая ссылка в гугле https://superuser.com/questions/143119

Comment: Отметьте ответ, если он помог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Легче будет переустановить Python и в первом же окне установки нажать галочку PATH. Либо мучатся вручную. Все способы есть по ссылке: https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/